# Rust passing features to dependency

Tags: rust, cargo-features

I have a system with three layers. The lowermost layer is an external C library, then I have created a wrapper library and finally a pure rust library on top. I build the C library with a `build.rs` script in the wrapper library. The C library is built with cmake and must be configured with `-DFEATURE1=ON` and `-DFEATURE2=ON` commandline switches.

I have configured rust features `feature1` and `feature2` in the `Cargo.toml` file of the wrapper library:

`wrapper/Cargo.toml:`

```ini
[features]
feature1=[]
feature2=[]
...
```

and in `build.rs` I use the `cfg!()` macro to pass the correct options to cmake:

```
use cmake::Config;
...
let mut config = Config::new("");
if !cfg(feature1) {
    config.define("FEATURE1", "ON");
}
```

When I build the wrapper library I can pass the correct features to the build step with:

```
bash% cargo build --features=feature1
```

and the wrapper library *and* the underlying C library are correctly built. But when I try to initiate the build from the pure rust library it seems the feature requests are not passed correctly down to the wrapper library:

`rustlib/Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies.wrapper]
path="wrapper"
features=["feature1"]
...
```

have also tried with the commandline alternative:

```
bash% cargo build --features=wrapper/feature1
```

In both cases the end result is that the feature request does not reach the final C library.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `cfg!(feature = "feature1")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build scripts do not have the features enabled as `cfg` as far as I know. I don't know why it works when you invoke `cargo build` on the package directly.

[To inspect enabled features in build scripts, check the existence of the environment variable `CARGO_FEATURE_<name>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#build-scripts).